# D3js v4 reading csv file in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, csv, angular, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.csv method to read a csv file from my Angular 2 app.
But it does not read the file from physical path i.e. from my directory structure. 
It tries to load file from http://localhost:4200/angular-src/src/app/components/csvgraph/data2.csv. Which gives 404.

I am using following code to read the file:

```
d3.csv('/angular-src/src/app/components/csvgraph/data2.csv', function(err,data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You should be used it as folllowing: ../app/components/csvgraph/data2.csv

Answer (score 2):

Loading the data via d3.csv() method in Angular doesn't work.

You need to:

1. Place your csv file in your src/assets folder
2. Inside your component, import HttpClient and load the file as text using the get() method
3. Use d3.csvParse() to convert the text to json similar to what the d3.csv() method returns

-

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/flowers.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(data => {
       var objs = d3.csvParse(data);
       this.createChart(objs);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data file is in the same directory as the file containing this code. Simply use only the file name like the following:

```
d3.csv('data2.csv', function(err,data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

If it is somewhere outside, you can navigate one level outside using `../`. For example, if it is in a separate folder outside called `data`, then you can do:

```
d3.csv('../data/data2.csv', function(err,data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It is in the same folder as my component.ts file. But it access it through http://localhost:4200/data2.csv which gives 404.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to load a csv file which is stored locally, but when I went through the types that this method accepts, it turned out that it only accepts urls (no paths).

As a temporary solution you can upload your file somewhere in the cloud and include a link for it.

This is an example, you may try it

```
d3.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bigsnarfdude/515849391ad37fe593997fe0db98afaa/raw/f663366d17b7d05de61a145bbce7b2b961b3b07f/weather.csv', function(err,data){
  console.log(data);
})
```